# Testing the oscillating Universe hypothesis

Tags: cosmology

Imagine a Universe where there was no total collapse into $r=0$ and suffers periodic steps of oscillation. How could we gather evidence from a Universe that never collapsed totally and only suffered periodic (very long period, of course) stages. What could we observe? Naively, I would think on black dwarfs and exotic dark stars but I suppose periodic evolution of the Universe would have other "fingerprints". Have anyone asked for them? Remark: I am NOT asking about the Universe being a recycled Universe from another Universe after collapse (cosmic cyclic cosmology, by Penrose) but the idea that the Universe never collapsed totally for some unknown reason, and it experienced steps (with longer or shorter periods) in which its evolution was periodic.

Comment: What is the shape of this hypothetical universe? is it spherical, is it flat, is it hyperbolic? How much mass/energy does it have? You can't answer this question until you can tell us why it is collapsing, and, frankly, you can't even ask the question of why it's collapsing until you can tell us how it escaped the primordial black hole in the first place.

Comment: Oscillation  in three dimensions happens when energy is supplied to a system and a  preexisting status is disturbed. What would supply this energy to  the main stream model of an  expanding universe?